# Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, compiler-errors

I got this error when I load database:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Notice
>       Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0
>       Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>       Line Number: 120
>       Backtrace:
>       File: /home1/learnio3/public_html/application/controllers/Reading.php
>       Line: 9
>       Function: database
>
> ```
> File: /home1/learnio3/public_html/index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once
> ```

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');

}
```

database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => 'learnio3_bram',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'learnio3_book',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: the given code cannot generate that issue.Please check again

Comment: check your database setting.

Comment: Can you include the actual lines of code (and surrounding context)  mentioned in the error so we can get a better idea of whats happening? As it stands the question is too vague to answer..

Comment: check your database settings as @HikmatSijapati suggest, also do not load database manually, use ```autoload.php``` and autoload the settings.

Comment: Okay i will try to load database using autoload.php

Comment: Okay i found the solution i forgot to type the hostname ahahaha

Answer (score 5):

change hostname => ''  to  hostname => 'localhost' , dont keep it blank ,
Even if it is a webserver , cloud9 etc , pass 'localhost' although in  phpmyadmin host name is "%"